# ¿Como puedo llamar un actionresult desde un controlador diferente en asp mvc .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

```
 <h2>Modulo Mantenimientos</h2>
    <a href="FormEmpleados/Index" class="btn btn-primary">IR AL FORMULARIO DE EMPLEADOS</a>
<a href="Departamentos/Index" class="btn btn-primary">IR AL FORMULARIO DE DEPARTAMENTOS</a>
<a href="Cargos/Index" class="btn btn-primary">IR AL FORMULARIO DE CARGOS</a>
```

Saludos, lo que quiero hacer es tener un controlador solo de presentacion(ese codigo que les mostre) la cual le mostrara al usuario las opciones a las cuales el desee ingresar, ahora bien, estas opciones son formularios de OTRO controlador y cuando ejecuto el programa me aparece un error en vez de la otra pagina con el formulario, por lo cual quiero saber como puedo combinar el controlador principal con los actionresult de los demás controladores, espero haberme explicado bien y que alguien me pueda ayudar....

Comment: Hola, no se si esto te sirva <a href="@Url.Action("Crear", "AdministrarVideos")" class="nav-link">, @Url.Action(nombre de la funcion", nombre controlador)

Comment: @JorgeLuis, este comentario deberías escribirla como respuesta. Es exactamente lo que Ricardo busca.

Comment: @JorgeLuis GRACIAS, GRACIAS, GRACIAS, exactamente era lo que buscaba :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola puedes probar con esto:

> @Url.Action(nombre de la función, nombre controlador);

Lo puedes usar así:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Crear", "AdministrarVideos")" class="nav-link"/>
```